# How to quickly align objects into a grid?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2016

[image]

As seen in the picture, how do I quickly align them into 4 by 5 grid?

Microsoft Office 2016 X64, Windows 7 SP1 X64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each row: select the shapes in the row, then choose Format | Align | Align Middle.

For each column: select the shapes in the row, then choose Format | Align | Align Center.

Select all shapes in each row and group.

You now have one group per row.

Select all of the shapes and choose Format | Align | Distribute vertically.

Ungroup each set of shapes.

Repeat, but this time select all shapes in each column and group, then Format | Align | Distribute horizontally.
Ungroup.

Done.

Comment: That's what I would been doing. But this really does not help much if I had say, 15 by 15 cells. Thanks though.

Comment: Afraid not.  Sometimes the computer works for us, sometimes we work for it.  Someone with skill in VBA could probably automate this; for the occasional need, it wouldn't be worth the time it'd take.